# I try to load Poker Hand dataset(csv) into tensorflow, but the accuracy is always about 50%, how can I do with it?

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I try to train an MLP that just consists of a softmax. In tensorflow tutorials, they used mnist dataset, however, I try to use another one, Poker Hand Dataset(10 classes). But by my program, the accuracy is always about 50%, that is so bothersome.

Here is my code

```js
  # coding=utf-8
  from __future__ import print_function
  import tensorflow as tf
  import numpy as np
  import datetime

  class Arc:
      def __init__(self):
          self.filenames = ['train.csv', 'test.csv']
          self.batchSize = 128
          self.trainIters = 100000
          self.totalEpoch = 1
          self.min_after_dequeue = 256
          self.capacity = 640

      def readData(self, filenames=None):

          files = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

          reader = tf.TextLineReader()
          key, value = reader.read(files)

          record_defaults = [[1], [1], [4], [1], [8], [1], [2], [1], [11], [1], [5]]
          s1, c1, s2, c2, s3, c3, s4, c4, s5, c5, hand = tf.decode_csv(value,
                                                                    record_defaults=record_defaults)
          features = tf.pack(tf.to_float([s1, c1, s2, c2, s3, c3, s4, c4, s5, c5]))
          hand = tf.one_hot(hand, 10, 1, 0, -1, tf.int32)

          features_batch, hand_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                                                [features, hand],
                                                batch_size=self.batchSize,
                                                capacity=self.capacity,
                                                min_after_dequeue=self.min_after_dequeue)

          return features_batch, hand_batch

      def fullyConnected(self, incoming, n_units, bias=True,
                   regularizer=None, weight_decay=0.001, trainable=True,
                   name="FullyConnected"):

          if isinstance(incoming, tf.Tensor):
              input_shape = incoming.get_shape().as_list()
          elif type(incoming) in [np.array, list, tuple]:
              input_shape = np.shape(incoming)
          else:
              raise Exception("Invalid incoming layer")

          assert len(input_shape) > 1, "Incoming Tensor shape must be at least 2-D"

          n_inputs = int(np.prod(input_shape[1:]))

          with tf.name_scope(name) as scope:
              W_init = tf.uniform_unit_scaling_initializer(dtype=tf.float32, seed=None)

              W_regul = None
              if regularizer:
                  if regularizer == 'L1':
                      W_regul = lambda x: tf.mul(tf.nn.l2_loss(x), weight_decay, name='L2-Loss')
                  elif regularizer == 'L2':
                      W_regul = lambda x: tf.mul(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(x)), weight_decay, name='L1-Loss')

              with tf.device(''):
                  try:
                      W = tf.get_variable(scope + 'W', [n_inputs, n_units], tf.float32, W_init, W_regul)
                  except Exception as e:
                      W = tf.get_variable(scope + 'W', [n_inputs, n_units], tf.float32, W_init)
                      if regularizer is not None:
                          if regularizer == 'L1':
                              W = lambda x: tf.mul(tf.nn.l2_loss(W), weight_decay, name='L2-Loss')
                          elif regularizer == 'L2':
                              W = lambda x: tf.mul(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(W)), weight_decay, name='L1-Loss')

              b = None
              if bias:
                  b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.)
                  with tf.device(''):
                      b = tf.get_variable(scope + 'b', [n_units], tf.float32, b_init, W_regul, trainable=trainable)

              inference = incoming

              if len(input_shape) > 2:
                  inference = tf.reshape(inference, [-1, n_inputs])

              inference = tf.matmul(inference, W)
              if b: inference += b

          return inference

      def network(self, net):
          net = self.fullyConnected(net, 10)
          net = tf.nn.softmax(net)
          return net

      def run(self):
          features, hand = self.readData(['train.csv'])

          x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,
                       shape=[None, 10],
                       name='Placeholder_X')
          y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,
                       shape=[None, 10],
                       name='Placeholder_Y')
          pred = self.network(x)

          cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=[1]))
          optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

          correctPred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
          accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPred, tf.float32))

          init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

          startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
          with tf.Session() as sess:
              sess.run(init)
              coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
              threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
              iter = 1
              while iter * self.batchSize < self.trainIters:
                  example, label = sess.run([features, hand])

                  try:
                      sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: example, y: label})
                  except Exception as e:
                      print(e.message)

                  if iter % 10 == 0:
                      loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: example, y: label})

                      print("Iter " + str(iter * self.batchSize) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                      "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                      "{:.5f}".format(acc))
                  iter += 1

              coord.request_stop()
              coord.join(threads)
           print('all done')

          endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
          fitTime = (endTime - startTime)
          print("Training Time:", fitTime)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      net = Arc()
      net.run()
```

I got the result as

```js
    Iter 1280, Minibatch Loss= 2.210387, Training Accuracy= 0.40625
    Iter 2560, Minibatch Loss= 2.371088, Training Accuracy= 0.35156
    Iter 3840, Minibatch Loss= 1.723017, Training Accuracy= 0.42188
    Iter 5120, Minibatch Loss= 1.650101, Training Accuracy= 0.43750
    ....
    ....
    Iter 98560, Minibatch Loss= 0.990002, Training Accuracy= 0.54688
    Iter 99840, Minibatch Loss= 1.142664, Training Accuracy= 0.52344
    all done
    Training Time: 0:00:12.081167
```

What mistake did I make? I guess maybe the queue caused that?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at it and there are a lot of errors in your code

- no activation function
- only one layer of fully connected that has very little capacity
- the print of the loss value is not displaying the correct value
- no encoding of the categorical input value (encode s1 as 4 one_hot encode and c1 as 13 one_hot encode and concatenate the result)